# Binary Log MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backups, binary-log

I have some binary log files from localhost but when i write

```
     mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000001 > statament.sql
```

or a text file it just returns gibberish i.e.

```
    /*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
    /*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
    DELIMITER /*!*/;
    # at 4
    #120919 11:08:54 server id 1  end_log_pos 106   Start: binlog v 4, server v 5.1.33-        community-log created 120919 11:08:54 at startup
    ROLLBACK/*!*/;
    BINLOG '
    potZUA8BAAAAZgAAAGoAAAAAAAQANS4xLjMzLWNvbW11bml0eS1sb2cAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACmi1lQEzgNAAgAEgAEBAQEEgAAUwAEGggAAAAICAgC
    '/*!*/;
    # at 106
    #120919 11:26:07 server id 1  end_log_pos 125   Stop
    DELIMITER ;
    # End of log file
    ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
    /*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
```

So that is mainly what is bothering... I have not slaves set up ... any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It just shows an empty log file.  Have you done any updates, inserts or deletes since you started the master?

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply .. Yeah I did and executed this mysqlbinlog -u username -p --host=localhost test<mysql-bin.000001 only to return an error ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear '¦bin¦ÅYP' at line 1

Comment: EDIT: I now did this mysqlbinlog -u root -p --host=localhost <mysql-bin.000001 ..  I thought it worked but it didn't as I removed some rows there and here ... and launched the cmd but nothing :(

Comment: Change your < to a >.   mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000001 > statament.sql

Comment: What that does is convert the binary file to an sql statement ....

Comment: Yes. That is what mysqlbinlog does. Dump a binary log file into a SQL file. It does not import data.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL binary log by definition is logging the data manipulations in binary form to save time and space for processing. So when you examine them, you should add `--base64-output=decode-rows` option to `mysqlbinlog` client have the the output decoded.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
mysqlbinlog --no-defaults --base64-output=decode-rows -v mysql-bin.000001 > statament.sql
```

Instead of  `--no-defaults --base64-output=decode-row -v`

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your first answer, however could you please add some details on the solution you proposed ?

Comment: what infomation?

Comment: Your answer could not be so clear for others, I've edited to make it more readable. You can also describe why this solution is better.